# Find out when a <button> button caused a postback in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

What's a simple good way to find out if a html button (the newer  not input) caused the postback?

Comment: Do you mean an ASP.NET button control?

Comment: Based on the variety of answers below, I think it would be desirable to clarify on the type of button (HTML, HTMLButton, or ASP.NET button).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the button is a [`HtmlButton` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlbutton.aspx) then you can just handle its [`ServerClick` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlbutton.serverclick.aspx):

```
<button id="MyButton" runat="server" onserverclick="MyButton_Click">Foo</button>
```

And then in your code-behind:

```
protected void MyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    // if you reach here it means that MyButton was clicked
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way to do it is to add an OnClick event and just add sample code in the code behind.  Then I usually add a breakpoint in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to know how server-side ASP.NET code can determine if a given HTML button was pressed to cause the post back?

I can't think of any excellent solutions.  Two sub-par solutions below:

1.) Add a client-side onclick to the button and have it modify a form element that the server has access to (i.e. hdnButtonClicked).  The page_load will check that element and the value will allow it to determine if the HTML button was clicked.

2.) Have the button trigger a server-side method.  Easiest way is to convert the button to an ASP.NET control and wire it up with an event handler but I'm sure you could work up some JavaScript to trigger a server-side method.

Unfortunately, I don't think information pertaining to how an HTML form was submitted is available on post back without some form of client side preparation.  ASP.NET does this behind the scenes.